# MYSQL intentando obtener un id específico como string

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, grocery-crud

Pues eso, estoy tratando de obtener un id específico como string desde una consulta realizada en el modelo para llamar a la función en el controlador y pasarlo como string. El problema es que creo que lo convierte a string pero no lo devuelve correctamente.

La situación es: dos tablas que se unen para mostrar filas compuestas por intervalos y citas, imagino que las citas llevarán un id relacionado a cada intervalo, entonces me haría falta el id de este intervalo para poderlo pasar como oculto en el controlador.

**Función (Modelo)**

```
public function get_idintervalo($idCarga) {

$query = $this->db->query('SELECT intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario 
        FROM intervaloshorarios, citas');

        $sql = "SELECT intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario 
            FROM intervaloshorarios, citas
        WHERE (citas.idIntervaloHorario = intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario) and citas.idIntervaloHorario =  $idCarga ";

        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $qry = $this->db->query($sql, array($row->idIntervaloHorario));
        }
```

**Controller (versión reducida)**

```
public function entregas_lista($idCarga) {

$query = $this->Intervalos_Model->get_idintervalo($idCarga);

        $crud->where('entregas.idCitas =', $idCarga);      

        if ($crud->getState() == "add") {
            $crud->change_field_type('idCitas', 'hidden', $idCarga);
            $crud->change_field_type('idIntervaloHorario', 'hidden', $query);
        }
}
```

**Resultado de var_dump**

0object(CI_DB_mysqli_result)#23 (8) { ["conn_id"]=> object(mysqli)#16 (19) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(12) ["client_info"]=> string(79) "mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 76b08b24596e12d4553bd41fc93cccd5bac2fe7a $" ["client_version"]=> int(50011) ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) ["connect_error"]=> NULL ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["host_info"]=> string(20) "localhost via TCP/IP" ["info"]=> NULL ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["server_info"]=> string(21) "5.5.5-10.1.21-MariaDB" ["server_version"]=> int(50505) ["stat"]=> string(139) "Uptime: 651888 Threads: 1 Questions: 47786 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 203 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 158 Queries per second avg: 0.073" ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["protocol_version"]=> int(10) ["thread_id"]=> int(2900) ["warning_count"]=> int(0) } ["result_id"]=> object(mysqli_result)#24 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(12) ["type"]=> int(0) } ["result_array"]=> array(0) { } ["result_object"]=> array(0) { } ["custom_result_object"]=> array(0) { } ["current_row"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> NULL ["row_data"]=> NULL }

Como véis se puede perfectamente pasar el id de la cita por la variable ($idCarga) pero no puedo obtener el id de la cita que corresponde a cada intervalo. ¿Alguna solución?

Comment: citas.idIntervaloHorario =  ".$idCarga." tal vez eso falle lo tienes dentro de la string sin concatenar

Comment: por que pasarlo como string cuando su valor original es un int?

Comment: porque al otro lado en el controlador, cuando llamo a la función y paso la variable por el hidden me salta el error típico de 'cannot convert array to string', voy a probar lo de @Saantty

Comment: ¿Cómo se concatenaría correctamente? estoy probando con `.$idCarga.` y no funciona

Comment: Si citas.idIntervaloHorario es String entonces citas.idIntervaloHorario = ' ".$idCarga." ' " con comillas simples

Comment: Si tu error es 'cannot conver array to string' el problema no es que sea int, el problema es que es una array, tendrías que sacar el valor de el, para se necesita ver que estas poniendo en el return de get_idintervalo

Comment: Coincido con @Sergio1871 y limitando  a responder como obtener un int como string, podrías modificar la consulta asi: `CONVERT(CHAR(25),intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario )`

Comment: Pero si supuestamente ya estoy devolviendo un array con `foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $qry = $this->db->query($sql, array($row->idIntervaloHorario));
        }`

Comment: Bueno pues el error no me lo da pero lo que creo que que la consulta está mal porque al rellenar el campo con el id correspondiente (automáticamente con esa consulta) no lo pilla y no deja guardar el formulario

Answer (score 0):

El error `cannot convert array to string` dice "no se puede convertir un array en string" ya que en la linea del controlador `$crud->change_field_type('idIntervaloHorario', 'hidden', $query);` estás consultando un array (`$query`), deberias iterarlo con un `foreach` dentro del `if`:

```
foreach ( $query as $item ) {
   $crud->change_field_type('idIntervaloHorario', 'hidden', $item['id'] );
}
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Hola! antes que nada gracias por responder pero no funciona, con esto: `if ($crud->getState() == "add") {
            $crud->change_field_type('idCitas', 'hidden', $idCarga);
            
            foreach ($query as $item) {
                $crud->change_field_type('idIntervaloHorario', 'hidden', $item['idIntervaloHorario']);
            }
            
        }`
Salta el error:
`Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` en la línea 94, es decir en la del foreach

Comment: Que error te arroja al intentar con ese código?

Comment: Este `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` y no entiendo por qué, todo parece estar bien, lo da en la misma línea donde empieza el foreach @Paul Tejada

Comment: podrías probar imprimir la variable `$query` antes del `foreach` con `var_dump($query)` para ver que información tiene, tal vez tiene algo que tu no esperas tener...

Comment: Creo que está pasando nulo. Subo lo que arroja a la pregunta.

Comment: el código del modelo no esta completo, le falta la llave de cierre de función y la sentencia `return`, creo que estas retornando la variable `$query` en vez de devolver `$qry` que es la que almacena la información esperada...

Comment: Lo siento, se ve que lo copié mal del código original pero sí que está completo

Answer (score 0):

segun lo que veo tu modelo deberia quedar asi con la linea que creo le falta:

```
public function get_idintervalo($idCarga) {

  $query = $this->db->query('SELECT intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario 
    FROM intervaloshorarios, citas');

  $sql = "SELECT intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario 
      FROM intervaloshorarios, citas
  WHERE (citas.idIntervaloHorario = intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario) and citas.idIntervaloHorario =  $idCarga ";

  foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
      $qry = $this->db->query($sql, array($row->idIntervaloHorario));
  }
  return $qry;
}
```

Fijate en las 2 ultimas lineas.